# DB2 Query issue

Tags: db2

```
SELECT
    Q."COLUMN1"     
FROM
(SELECT
    "COLUMN1",
    CAST ((SELECT CAST (RTRIM (PARAM) AS VARCHAR(50)) FROM TABLE_VIEW WHERE PARAM_ID = :ID) AS VARCHAR(50)) AS "COLUMN2"
FROM ("TABLE1")Q 
WHERE 
    RTRIM(CAST("COLUMN1" AS CHAR(10))) IN (SELECT VALUE_1 FROM TABLE (SPLIT_PARAMS(CAST(Q."COLUMN2" AS VARCHAR(50)),',',5)))
```

COLUMN2 gets its value from a separate table based on the input provided at run time.

The filter used in the query consists of a used defined table valued function that is used to split the comma separated valued to individual values.

The query throws the error message as:

"FUNCTION NOT SUPPORTED. SQLCODE=-270, SQLSTATE=42997"

Can anyone help me find the cause of the issue.

Comment: The complete error message would contain a reason code, which would help you understand, well, the reason.

Comment: I believe it's complaining because you're trying to use a column reference as input to a table-valued function, which appears to be verboten.  IOW, `SPLIT_PARAMS` can only be used on, well, parameters, and not `Q.Column2` (the fact that you have a comma-delimited column is a different red flag...)